# Why doesn't this Check constraint work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, check-constraints, check-constraint

I have created a check constraint in SQL Server 2005, but this check constraint doesn't work. The SQL Server Management Studio tells me by an insert statement the following message:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "MY_CHECK_CONSTAINT". The conflict occurred in database "MY_DB", table "dbo.MY_TABLE", column 'MY_COLUMN'.

I have added the check constraint with the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MY_CHECK_CONSTRAINT CHECK (dbo.MY_FUNCTION(MY_PARAMETER)<1)
```

The calling function "MY_FUNCTION" returns an int.

My target is that if my function returns an int which is less than 1 the insert statement can successfully be completed and if the return value is bigger than 0 the insert statement has to be terminated.

My problem now is that my function returns the value 0 but the insert statement has been terminated always. What am I doing wrong?

The code of my function is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(@MY_PARAMETER uniqueidentifier) 
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN 
    declare @return int = 0
    SET @return = (SELECT COUNT(MY_COLUMN) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN= @MY_PARAMETER )
return @return 
END
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong is that your *assumption* that the function is returning 0 is incorrect. But we can't tell you why it's incorrect since you haven't shown us the code for it.

Comment: I have god added now the code of my function. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Just add a unique constraint on `MY_COLUMN`. Don't try and use a check constraint with a scalar UDF for this.

Comment: Hi Martin, I can't use an unique constraint because MY_COLUMN can be NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem in 100%. Try this new 
example below. Now my table table1 is empty, and I cannot insert 
any number into it :) Very interesting situation, absolutely the 
same as yours, I believe.

*"Maybe when your UDF code is executed, it already sees this same 

row which you're just trying to insert (it sees it's in the table). 

I don't know the inner workings and don't have much time now to check it. 

But that could be the issue. My UDF doesn't perform a check based on some 

SELECT in the same table, that's what's conceptually different between 

your example and my example."*

OK, after 5 more minutes of research, turns out my guess was right.
When your UDF is called, it sees the row you're just trying
to insert.

See the accepted answer here.

[Check constraint UDF with multiple input parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946423/check-constraint-udf-with-multiple-input-parameters-not-working)

So - mystery uncovered, it seems :)

```
--- 1 ---

USE [test]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ContainsNumber]    Script Date: 11/26/2013 07:06:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContainsNumber]
(
        @number int
)
RETURNS INT AS

BEGIN

declare @result int

select @result = count(*)
from test.dbo.table1
where
number = @number

if (@result > 0) 
begin
    set @result = 1
end

return @result

END


GO



--- 2 ---

USE [test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[table1]    Script Date: 11/26/2013 07:06:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [number] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_table1] CHECK  (([dbo].[ContainsNumber]([number])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_table1]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help :) now everything works fine. That was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe you can try this in your code:

```
SELECT @return = COUNT(MY_COLUMN) 
FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = @MY_PARAMETER
```

instead of what you did.

2) Try naming the variable not @return but e.g. @result.

3) Try walking your function outside of its normal call.

4) Also, you might want to try this test below. 
I don't see any issues with it ... But OK, 
it's not 100% the same as yours.

This check constraint below works fine and uses
my **user defined function** IsEvenNumber.

```
----- 1 -----

USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsEvenNumber]
(
        @number int
)
RETURNS INT AS

BEGIN

declare @result int

set @result = 1

if (((@number) % 2) <> 0)
begin
    set @result = 0
end


return @result


END



GO




----- 2 -----


USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [number] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Table1] CHECK  (([dbo].[IsEvenNumber]([number])<(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Table1]
GO



----- 3 -----


insert into table1(number) values (3) -- OK

insert into table1(number) values (10) -- FAILED

insert into table1(number) values (0) -- FAILED

insert into table1(number) values (5) -- OK
```

Comment: If I do your solution everything works fine but when I try to do the same with my function and my table so i get the following error message: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_MY_CONSTRAINT". The conflict occurred in database "MY_DB", table "dbo.MY_TABLE", column 'MY_COLUMN'.

Comment: I don't know why but I can't alter my table to add the check constraint without placing the NOCHECK.

Comment: I tried to call my function outside with a fixed value as a parameter and I'm sure that my function works as I want.

Comment: Maybe when your UDF code is executed, it already sees this same row which you're just trying to insert (it sees it's in the table). I don't know the inner workings and don't have much time now to check it. But that could be the issue. My UDF doesn't perform a check based on some SELECT in the same table, that's what's conceptually different between yours and mine.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem but I wonder why I can't alter my table and add the check constraint without the extension of NOCHECK

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly but maybe because the existing data in tour table already violates your constraint.